# Is it possible to have two projects sharing one master view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two different projects within a solution in ASP.NET MVC. Is there a way to have a master view shared between both projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to embed the master file into a shared assembly and [implement a custom VirtualPathProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/shahpiyush/archive/2007/03/09/Sharing-Master-Pages-amongst-Applications-by-Embedding-it-in-a-Dll_2E00_.aspx).